# grouping related data in csv excel file

Tags: python, regex, grouping

this is a csv excel file

```
   Receipt Name    Address      Date       Time    Total
    25007   A      ABC pte ltd   3/7/2016   10:40   12.30
    25008   A      ABC ptd ltd   3/7/2016   11.30   6.70
    25009   B      CCC ptd ltd   4/7/2016   07.35   23.40
    25010   A      ABC pte ltd   4/7/2016   12:40   9.90
```

how do i retrieve the dates and time and group them to respectively company A and B such that the output would be something like: (A, 3/7/2016, 10:40, 11.30, 4/7/2016 12:40), (B, 4/7/2016, 07:35)

My existing code is:

```
datePattern = re.compile(r"(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+(\d+:\d+)")  
dateDict =dict()    

for i, line in enumerate(open('sample_data.csv')):
    for match in re.finditer(datePattern,line):
        if match.group(1) in dateDict:
            dateDict[match.group(1)].append(match.group(2))
        else:
            dateDict[match.group(1)] = [match.group(2),]
```

However it only works for grouping date and time but now i want to include name as part of the grouping as well. *Using csv module would be preferred

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want a dictionary from company name to a timestamp (date + time). In this case you want the company names to be used as dictionary keys. Is this correct?

Comment: yes that is right. the company name which is the dictionary key should contain the date and time as its value

Comment: Why are you using a regex?

Comment: do you have better ideas? this is the best i can come up with...would like to try csv modules

Comment: My answer to your previous question shows you how to read the file using the csv lib, after that grouping is trivial with a defaultdict

Comment: i seem to have deleted the previous question. my other question with your answer is about pairings and frozen sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming your data actually looks like:

```
Receipt,Name,Address,Date,Time,Items
25007,A,ABC pte ltd,4/7/2016,10:40,"Cheese, Cookie, Pie"
25008,A,CCC pte ltd,4/7/2016,11:30,"Cheese, Cookie"
25009,B,CCC pte ltd,4/7/2016,07:35,"Chocolate"
25010,A,CCC pte ltd,4/7/2016,12:40," Butter, Cookie"
```

then it is pretty trivial to group:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from csv import reader
with open("test.csv") as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    group_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for _, name, _, dte, time, _ in reader(f):
        group_dict[name].append((dte, time))

from  pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dict(group_dict))
```

which would give you:

```
'A': [('4/7/2016', '10:40'), ('4/7/2016', '11:30'), ('4/7/2016', '12:40')],
 'B': [('4/7/2016', '07:35')]}
```

If you don't want the date repeating, then also group on that:

```
with open("test.csv") as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    group_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for _, name, _, dte, time, _ in reader(f):
        group_dict[name, dte].append(time)

from  pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dict(group_dict))
```

Which would give you:

```
{('A', '4/7/2016'): ['10:40', '11:30', '12:40'], ('B', '4/7/2016'): ['07:35']}
```

Comment: there's a  ValueError: too many values to unpack. i presume there is something wrong with 'for _, name, _, dte, time, _ in reader(f):' ?

Comment: Post the data exactly as you see it in your file, it is definitely not as you have it in your question

Comment: sorry about that , i got that working because my source file has some more fields that i did not include in the sample here. One other problem is that how do i exclude the header because its printing "receipt", "name" etc

Comment: Did my last solution work for your previous question?

Comment: That is correct  output no? Or are you just grouping on date and name?

Comment: yeap! my output for this after i add another item for B with the same date is: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [('4/7/2016', '10:40')], 'C': [('5/7/2016', '14.5')], 'B': [('5/7/2016', '8:40'), ('5/7/2016', '6:30')], 'Name': [('Date', 'Time')], 'D': [('6/7/2016', '21.3')]})      

As you can see the header is printed and for B is it possible to display the same date just once like  
'B': [('5/7/2016', '8:40','6:30']   ?

Comment: See the edit, you essentially want to group by name and date

Comment: hey that seems to be what i am looking for! upvoted you but its not public, thanks for your great help and god bless!

Comment: No worries, you need a certain amount of rep to upvote. If the last answer worked you can accept that top close the question also.

Comment: Hi sorry just one last thing. how do i sort the timing to be ascending value?
do i add .sorted for  group_dict[name, dte].append(time)?

Comment: `for v in group_dict.values():v.sort()` at the end, you could do a bisect.insort as you go but to no real advantage

Comment: hi i am back again. sorry but i am trying to expand the program. so far the program is able to sort the different shop with their respective sales date and timing. i was wondering if there is a way for me to add the receipt number after every time so it would be like 
 ('A', '4/7/2016'): ['10:40',25007]
thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, just store tuples in the list (time, number).

Comment: guess its a formatting issue with the pprint. i did .extend([time, rec]) and got all the details but all the receipt only appear under the time. how do i play around with pprint such that only name and date gets a new paragraph but the time and receipt number stays on the same line?

Comment: so now i got a new column which is 'total'(edited on the main question) and i hope to display the total amount for each day. how do i include the code which would count the total amount of different timing and store the total amount beside every date?

Comment: *UPDATED* my queries are resolved. sorry for spamming here but i cant seem to delete my previous comment

Comment: sorry but is there a reason why default dict is used in this case?

Comment: @DarrylDan, yes, you have duplicate keys so it is used to group the data

Answer (score -1):

It can be done pretty easily using Pandas module:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')

df.groupby(['Name','Date']).Time.apply(list).reset_index().to_csv('d:/temp/out.csv', index=False)
```

D:\temp\out.csv:

```
Name,Date,Time
A,3/7/2016,"['10:40', '11.30']"
A,4/7/2016,['12:40']
B,4/7/2016,['07.35']
```

Comment: Do i have to install anything it says no panda module found.. are there alternatively method of doing it?

Comment: @DarrylDan, yes, Pandas module has to be installed extra... And yes, there are quite a few alternative methods

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use Pandas, this is a possible solution. It's not the most elegant since your csv format is relatively clunky to parse. If you can change the format to use a non-whitespace field separator, using a proper csv parsing library (like `pandas` or Python's built-in `csv` module) would be preferable.

```
import re

datePattern = re.compile(r"(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+(\d+[:.]\d+)")
companyPattern = re.compile(r"^\s+\d+\s+(\w+)")
companyDict = {}

for i, line in enumerate(open('sample_data.csv')):
    # skip csv header
    if i == 0:
        continue

    timestampMatch = datePattern.search(line)
    companyMatch   = companyPattern.search(line)

    # filter out any malformed lines which don't match
    if timestampMatch is None or companyMatch is None:
        continue

    date = timestampMatch.group(1)
    time = timestampMatch.group(2)
    company = companyMatch.group(1)

    companyDict.setdefault(company, []).append("{} {}".format(date, time))
```

Note that the time field is inconsistent as to whether it uses `.` or `:` for the hour/minute delimiter so I've taken this into account.

Running this on your sample data results in the following value for `companyDict`:

```
{'A': ['3/7/2016 10:40', '3/7/2016 11.30', '4/7/2016 12:40'], 'B': ['4/7/2016 07.35']}
```

Comment: thats weird, it doesnt print out anything when i do "print companyDict"

Comment: Well, that's probably because your data doesn't look like in the sample as you mentioned elsewhere. To the downvoter, a reasoning for the downvote would be appreciated.